# Plot company's stock prices against company's quarterly net profits

Tags: stocks

Is there any service where I could plot company's stock prices against company's quarterly net profits for example?

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the P/E ratio tells you? Okay, well not profits, but revenues. Seems close enough though.

Answer (score 3):

While not free, I am familiar with *[ShareOwner Education Inc.](http://www.shareowner.com/index.html)* from Canada, who publish a magazine, a software package (the [Stock Study Guide](http://www.shareowner.com/stock-market-education/stock-study-guide-and-data.html)), and stock data files for their software.

*ShareOwner's* software and data provide charts like what you're asking for: stock prices vs. profits.  Their database contains stocks from major U.S. and Canadian exchanges.  Here are two simplified examples of what the charts in their magazines & software look like:

[image: Stock Study Guide chart example #1]
      
[image: Stock Study Guide chart example #2]

Above, the red bars are the stock price range bars, the green line plots earnings per share, and the blue line plots revenue. *ShareOwner* advocates an approach to stock investing where the aim is to buy "great" stocks that are "on sale".  "Great" stocks have consistent, growing revenue & EPS, and are considered "on sale" when cheap relative to historical valuation.  Approaches like this are considered [Growth At a Reasonable Price (GARP)](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/garp.asp).

I'm familiar with *ShareOwner's* products because I used to be a subscriber. However, I did come across similar software & data packages when I did some research of my own for these kinds of charts & services:

- [Stock Investor Pro](http://www.aaii.com/stock-investor-pro) software and subscription from the [*American Association of Individual Investors*](http://www.aaii.com/).  I think their software can be used to make charts like those above.
- The [StockCentral](http://www.iclub.com/products/sc.asp) subscription and [Toolkit](http://www.iclub.com/products/tk6.asp) software from [*ICLUBcentral Inc.*](http://www.iclub.com/default.asp) Again, I think their software can be used to make charts like those above.

There may be more.  None of these software + data solutions are cheap, so do some due diligence before you buy.

Finally, if you're interested in learning more about these kinds of approaches, in addition to courses/material from the companies above, I'm aware of the book [Take Stock](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0793141494) by Ellis Traub.  I read the first edition (earlier link) a long time ago; the latest (3rd) edition seems to be [available at iCLUBcentral](http://www.iclub.com/products/tsbook.asp), but not Amazon.

Comment: Thanks for good answer. I tried to upvote but since Im newbie with no reputation I couldnt do it.